# Apache Camel TCP client with Permanent connection to a TCP server Asynchronous response

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, netty

I need to implement a tcp/ip client which connects to existing tcp server with a permanent connection. the client has to send multiple requests and response arrives asynchronously. I have use netty to do the integration part. I have to ensure that the response is done for the relevant request. How to implement this  using apache camel.

```
      rest()
                .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .post("/tcp")               
                .type(RequestBean.class)
                .route()
                .process(this::transformTcpMessage)
                .to("netty://tcp://127.0.0.1:9898")
                .endRest();
```

This is What I need to achieve. this TCP client need to have a permeant connection and server may response asynchronously. So I need to make sure that the relevant response has been send to the relevant request.

Comment: We cant help with no code even an exception could help.

Comment: @Namphibian Actually I need a solution idea to implement  such tcp client using camel.

Comment: There is a lot of ways to create a solution in camel. However without code it is kinda of hard to help. Code is real part of the solution we can work with. Off the top of my head  if you can save the request with an identifier somewhere and then when you get a reply(hopefully with an identifier) you can match the request to the response using the id. However there is way to little detail in your question to see if this is possible even

Comment: @Namphibian In my case what you suggest is to create a custom  queue that saves the exchange and some other parameters and ones the response comes find the exchange with the parameters and response back

Comment: Look at the claim check EIP.

Comment: Any Idea how to make this netty client make a permanent connection to the server. My understanding is that once the response received for a request the connection get closed

Comment: Its rest and http. That is the way it works. If you want a permanent connection you can look at websockets or just raw tcp/ip. Request/Response is how HTTP works even if the socket stays open.

Comment: I need permanent connection from netty to  the external server not for the rest part  is it possible?